# VBA - Bypass Application.evaulate limit

Tags: vba, calculation

So I got an string that contains numeric values that I want to calculate into a sum. I tried to use `Application.evaluate` but I noticed that there is a limit on the amount of characters I can use in the calculation. Is there a  way to bypass this or fix it so I can calculate it? I'm thinking of writing my own "calculator" but it feels like a bit to much and there must be an easier way to do it?

> 0 /(2^16) +  3 /(2^16) +  53 /(2^16) +  139573 /(2^16) +  1844259
>   /(2^16) +  4005892 /(2^16) +  7546905 /(2^16) +  14629148 /(2^16) + 
>   15078164 /(2^16) +  7477520 /(2^16) + 3158785/(2^16) + 1258795/(2^16)
>   + 538914/(2^16) + 396079/(2^16) + 12305/(2^16) + 1555/(2^16) + 258/(2^16) + 8/(2^16) + 4/(2^16)

Another example:

> 1215  /(  7168  +  5922  +  5390  +  7034  +  10410  +  10494  + 
>   12113  +  6607  +  448  +  67  +  2996  +  4103  +  15581  +  18432  +
>   7299  +  1215  +  177  +  11  +  3   + 0   )*100

Comment: Could you not just split it in half? Why not `Application.Evaluate(1st_half_of_math) + Application.Evaluate(2nd_half_of_math)`?

Comment: @QHarr Sorry, updated it

Comment: @Taelsin Thought about it but can't figure how to do it without breaking anything. lets say that is no "+" then I can't split it or if the calculation is 8/(6+2) that could break the calculation too.

Comment: Given what you have in your question, this will work: `Application.Evaluate("0 /(2^16) + 3 /(2^16) + 53 /(2^16) + 139573 /(2^16) + 1844259 /(2^16) + 4005892 /(2^16) + 7546905 /(2^16) + 14629148 /(2^16) + 15078164 /(2^16)") + Application.Evaluate("7477520 /(2^16) + 3158785/(2^16) + 1258795/(2^16) + 538914/(2^16) + 396079/(2^16) + 12305/(2^16) + 1555/(2^16) + 258/(2^16) + 8/(2^16) + 4/(2^16)")`

Comment: @Taelsin That is wierd. I did as you said and wrote in the Immediate and there it works but not when the program itself tries to run it, then I get Error 2015.

Comment: That error is three years out of date

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 Maybe so but I cant seem to get pass it in this calculation. When running a shorter one it works perfectly

Comment: Sorry I was joking. It's 2018 this year! It looks like your only option is going to be to write your own expression parser, evaluate the individual parts and then combine them... You could do with a better example because you keep saying things could change, and everyone is answering your question against the expression you provided!

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 yeah, my bad that I didn't make it explicit. Added another example but I think I will try to make my own as evaluate doesn't have a workaround for the 255 limit in my understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you stick it in a cell and read it back?

```
Sub test()

    Dim s As String

    s = "0 /(2^16) + 3 /(2^16) + 53 /(2^16) + 139573 /(2^16) + 1844259 /(2^16) + 4005892 /(2^16) + 7546905 /(2^16) + 14629148 /(2^16) + 15078164 /(2^16) + 7477520 /(2^16) + 3158785/(2^16) + 1258795/(2^16) + 538914/(2^16) + 396079/(2^16) + 12305/(2^16) + 1555/(2^16) + 258/(2^16) + 8/(2^16) + 4/(2^16)"

    Sheet1.Range("A1").Formula = "=" & s

    Debug.Print Sheet1.Range("A1").Value

    Sheet1.Range("A1").ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: This could be a solution but I'm trying to keep this part of the code away from the sheets until I see no other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Given that addition is commutative, can you not calculate half your expression (up to 3158785/(2^16)), assign the result to a variable, then calculate the rest of the expression and add that to the previous result?

Comment: In the current state I cant do that due to implicitly.

Comment: Ok. Given that all your terms have the same denominator, can you not just sum all the numerators, and then have a single term ... That should be a lot shorter!

Comment: Could be a solution but in case that a user would change something like adding another operator that wouldn't work